# Setting specific stylesheet for retina displays

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, media-queries, retina-display

I was searching for a method to set different stylesheets depending whether users device is non - retina or retina. I came across tons of different methods, so now I don't know which one to do. Although in my opinion this seems to be easier and more efficient one:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="myCss.css" media="screen and min-device-pixel-ratio: 2">
```

But I'm not sure it it is the latest syntax, will this work for all modern browsers (including ie9), is there a way to improve this method?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/ - Most likely you should not have enough custom styling to warrant a separate CSS file and the overhead associated with either different files or an additional request.  If you do have the need, you may want to handle it entirely on the server so the client gets tailored content.

Comment: IE9 will never be running on a Retina display anyway...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach with the `media` attribute in  the `link` tag is a good start. Although I would recommend using the new `media query` which you can use directly inside the `.css`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

You can do that as so:

```
@media only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
    /* The retina stuff here */
    }
```

Futher reading: http://menacingcloud.com/?c=highPixelDensityDisplays

Answer (score 2):

In your existing stylesheet

```
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
(min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```

From

[CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/)